# What are the different public transport options from Dublin airport to the city centre?

Tags: public-transport, ireland, dublin

Please mention the exact place in the city centre for each option.

And fare, if you remember please.

Please mention the maximum amount of luggage appropriate for each option.

I'm carrying two large suitcases. But happy to listen to all options irrespective of luggage, for future and knowledge.

Edit: so far, the options seem:

1. Air link bus, possibly suitable for one suitcase
2. Normal taxi outside the airport, possibly suitable for three suitcases
3. Possibly Uber

Comment: What have you found from your research so far ?

Comment: @blackbird yes thanks for reminding. Edited and added it in the question right now. Air link bus, black taxi and possibly Uber.

Comment: What do you mean by "mention the exact place in the city centre for each option"? The Airlink bus stops at multiple points in the city centre, for example. A taxi will stop whever you ask it to.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Besides the Airlink bus, you can take the local buses 16 or 41, which costs 2 euros instead of 6 like the Airlink

Personally I prefer this option

More info can be found here http://www.dublinbus.ie/